# How to install LEGO Marvel Super Heroes in Wine?

Tags: wine, games

Basically as the title suggests, I would like to know how to install that game under Wine in Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps involved to be able to play LEGO Marvel Super Heroes on your Ubuntu box:

- Install the latest Wine release from ppa: [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine)
- Install and configure Steam for Wine: [How can I install Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1784/how-can-i-install-steam)
- Run Steam with the `-no-dwrite` option: [Steam not displaying text on wine 1.5 running on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214361/steam-not-displaying-text-on-wine-1-5-running-on-ubuntu-12-04)
- Install LEGO Marvel from CD (or from an [.iso of this CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278912/mount-an-iso-image-in-wine))
- Configure your XBox controller (if available): [How do I get an XBOX 360 controller working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165210/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-360-controller-working)

Comment: I have installed Wine 1.7, and I've installed it from an iso however it doesn't load... so I don't know what to doom to fix it. From task manage in winetricks you can see that it loads for a few seconds then closes.

Comment: Is Steam running? You may also need some Windows .dll.

Comment: I'm not actually using Steam to run it, I'm just installed it from a normal installer. I've installed DirectX Visual C++ Libraries, etc

Comment: Marvel Super Hero does not run without Steam.

Comment: I have it on disc though..

Comment: A said: it needs to be activated through Steam.

Comment: Ok, so it does the same thing.