# Steam Interface messed up in Wine?

Tags: steam

Yeah I'm new to the linux community, I always adored Linux as my brother is an expert in linux on some online community of linux but he's been quite busy but since growing up with him he had Ubuntu and any other linux distros in the past installed for me.

I know the basics of linux and to understand it just a few bits and bobs I don't know from the basics that I should but I was trying to run wine (and he had wine and everything installed for me works flawlessly with Guild Wars 2) and the steam interface just looks like this link directs you to below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm83l.png

The reason why I was trying to get this to work in wine was to access one or two windows game in linux, theres literally just those that I bum and majority of em in linux and I'm not a fussy gamer I can say no to a heck of windows game and just play some linux ones that I adore but there is always one or few games in windows biting you in the arse.

Any ideas? Again I'm a total newbie, maybe one day I won't be one and use ArchLinux ;3

Comment: I've had better luck with [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/)

Comment: Try the solutions here http://askubuntu.com/questions/214361/steam-not-displaying-text-on-wine-1-5-running-on-ubuntu-12-04 - they should still work - you can test this by running with the `-no-dwrite` option in Wine (`Steam.exe -no-dwrite`).

Comment: Ah but like it says in there I don't have a DWrite DWORD already made file there yet, as it said to create one if you have none, I've done that and no changes :/

Comment: Oh thanks man I finally got it fixed, I did a stupid mistake on first attempt but fixed all that with a steam reinstall to gain the steam directory back in the wine edit area. Cheers a bunch!