# wineprefixes don't work

Tags: wine

it's that simple.

they don't

i've learned to create and call back wineprefixes (AND I ONLY WANT ONE)

but it doesn't really seem to matter.

wine or winetricks does whatever it wants and doesn't listen to you.

I type

```
env WINEDEBUG="fixme-all" WINEPREFIX="/home/t/./wine32" wine msiexec /i SteamInstall.msi
```

my program gets installed in wine32 without the ./

I type

```
env WINEDEBUG="fixme-all" WINEPREFIX="/home/t/wine32" wine msiexec /i SteamInstall.msi
```

it still installs in wine32 but also creates a .wine directory. (which was deleted to create the prefix)

I have lost all faith in wineprefixes.

they suck, they really really do.

---

I need to use 32bit version of wine 1.7.30 and install all my wine programs in the same prefix.

I also need dotnet40, corefonts and vcrun2010

how do I accomplish this master-feat of all the greek gods?

Comment: "wine32 without the ./" - do you understand what `./` means?

Answer (score 3):

They do work, you just are not using the correct variable - there is a list in [`man wine`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wine), here are the ones you will need:

> **WINEARCH**
>
> - Specifies the Windows architecture to support. It can be set either to `win32` (support only 32-bit applications), or to `win64`
>     (support both 64-bit applications and 32-bit ones in WoW64 mode).
> - The architecture supported by a given Wine prefix is set at prefix creation time and cannot be changed afterwards. When running
>     with an existing prefix, Wine will refuse to start if `WINEARCH` doesn't
>     match the prefix architecture.
>
> **WINEPREFIX**
>
> - If set, the content of this variable is taken as the name of the directory where wine stores its data *(the default is `$HOME/.wine`)*.
>     This directory is also used to identify the socket which is used to
>     communicate with the wineserver. All wine processes using the same
>     wineserver *(i.e.: same user)* share certain things like registry,
>     shared memory, and config file. By setting `WINEPREFIX` to different
>     values for different wine processes, it is possible to run a number of
>     truly independent wine processes.

So to create a 32bit wineprefix:

```
export WINEARCH="win32"
export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine-PROGRAM-NAME/
wineboot -u
```

Then use:

```
wine /PATH/TO/INSTALLER.exe
```

OR

```
wine msiexec /i /PATH/TO/INSTALLER.msi
```

in the same terminal, after the export command, or use `env` as I explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548909/running-net-4-0-application-with-wine/548921#548921) to use the installers in the wine path - so:

```
env WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32/"  wine msiexec /i SteamInstall.msi
```

The [AppDB entry](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1163) for Steam indicates you may need to fix font issue with steam in wine, there is a answer on that [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/214476/178596). Comment below this post here if you have issues.

N.B.
You can read up a bit on linux directory paths [here](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=17).